# Memory leaks in doubly linked list

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm pretty new to C programming.

I have an assignment in which we are supposed to create a doubly linked list of integers, and write some functions to manipulate them. We are being asked to prevent memory leaks, but I'm not really sure how to do that.

I have to `malloc`  a bunch of times in order to create and store nodes when making the linked list, and I'm pretty sure it's not a good idea to `malloc` enough space for a node and then free the pointer to it in the same place.

Therefore, my best guess is that I should free all nodes in the main function, when I will have printed their contents to the screen and they are no longer needed. I tried to implement a `kill` function that takes as input a reference `head` to the first node in the list, and which iterates over the nodes, freeing them as they go.

I went as far as installing valgrind to try and see if there were any memory leaks, and it looks like there are still some. I have no idea where they are coming from or how to fix the issue.

Here is the whole code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct Node{
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
     struct Node *previous;
 }Node;

 void print_dll(Node *head){
     Node *curr = head;
     while(curr != NULL){
         printf("%d\t", curr->data);
         curr = curr->next;
     }
     puts(" ");
 }

Node* create_dll_from_array(int array [], int arrSize){
     //this is a function that creates a doubly linked list 
     //with the contents of the array
     Node* current = (Node *) malloc (sizeof(Node * ));
     current->data = array[arrSize-1];
     current -> next = NULL;

     for(int i = 2; i <= arrSize; i++){
         //create a new node
         Node * temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
         //I would like the dll to be in the same order as the array, I        guess it isn't strictly necessary
         temp ->data = array[arrSize-i];
         temp -> next = current;
         current-> previous = temp;
         //now make temp the current
         current = temp;
     }
     current-> previous = NULL; 
     return current;
 }

  void insert_after(Node* head, int valueToInsertAfter, int valueToInsert ){
     if(head != NULL){
         Node * current = head;

         while(current-> data != valueToInsertAfter){
         //this while loop brings 'current' to the end of the list if
         //the searched value is not there
             if(current-> next != NULL){
                 current = current->next;
             }else{
                 break;
             }
         }
         //after exiting this loop, the current pointer is pointing
         //either to the last element of the dll or to the element 
         //we need to insert after

         Node *new = (Node *) malloc (sizeof(Node *));
         new->data = valueToInsert;
         new->next = current->next;
         new->previous = current;
         if(current->next != NULL){
             (current->next)->previous = new;
         }
         current->next = new;
     }
 }

 void delete_element(Node* head, int valueToBeDeleted){
     //work in progress
 }
 void kill(Node *head){
 //this is my attempt at freeing all the nodes in the doubly linked list
     Node *current;
     while(head!=NULL){
         current = head;
         head = head->next;
         free(head);
     }
 }
 int main(){
     int array [5] = {11, 2, 7, 22, 4};
     Node *head;

     /*Question 1*/
     //creates a doubly linked list from the array below
     head = create_dll_from_array(array, 5); ///size of the array is 5

     /* Question 2 */
    // print_dll(head);

     /*Question 3*/
     // to insert 13 after the first appearance of 7
     insert_after(head, 7, 13);
     print_dll(head);
     //to insert 29 after first appearance of 21
     insert_after(head, 21, 29);
     print_dll(head);

     /*Question 6*/
     //create a function to free the whole list

     kill(head);


     return 0;

 }
```

The main function here is given to us by the prof, we have to build out function around it.

I don't know why this is still appearing to lead to memory leaks, and if I', being honest, I don't really know where else they could occur. As far as I know, I need to keep all the memory until almost the last minute.

Please help,  I'm pretty lost here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Need to change all `malloc (sizeof(Node*))` to `malloc (sizeof(Node))`
2. Need to change `free(header)` to `free(current)` in the kill function.

The modified code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
} Node;

void print_dll(Node *head)
{
    Node *curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL) {
        printf("%d\t", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    puts(" ");
}

Node *create_dll_from_array(int array [], int arrSize)
{
    //this is a function that creates a doubly linked list
    //with the contents of the array
    Node *current = (Node *) malloc (sizeof(Node));
    current->data = array[arrSize - 1];
    current -> next = NULL;

    for(int i = 2; i <= arrSize; i++) {
        //create a new node
        Node *temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        //I would like the dll to be in the same order as the array, I guess it isn't strictly necessary
        temp ->data = array[arrSize - i];
        temp -> next = current;
        current-> previous = temp;
        //now make temp the current
        current = temp;
    }
    current-> previous = NULL;
    return current;
}

void insert_after(Node *head, int valueToInsertAfter, int valueToInsert )
{
    if(head != NULL) {
        Node *current = head;

        while(current-> data != valueToInsertAfter) {
            //this while loop brings 'current' to the end of the list if
            //the searched value is not there
            if(current-> next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        //after exiting this loop, the current pointer is pointing
        //either to the last element of the dll or to the element
        //we need to insert after

        Node *new = (Node *) malloc (sizeof(Node));
        new->data = valueToInsert;
        new->next = current->next;
        new->previous = current;
        if(current->next != NULL) {
            (current->next)->previous = new;
        }
        current->next = new;
    }
}

void delete_element(Node *head, int valueToBeDeleted)
{
    //work in progress
}
void kill(Node *head)
{
//this is my attempt at freeing all the nodes in the doubly linked list
    Node *current;
    while(head != NULL) {
        current = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(current);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int array [5] = {11, 2, 7, 22, 4};
    Node *head;

    /*Question 1*/
    //creates a doubly linked list from the array below
    head = create_dll_from_array(array, 5); ///size of the array is 5

    /* Question 2 */
    // print_dll(head);

    /*Question 3*/
    // to insert 13 after the first appearance of 7
    insert_after(head, 7, 13);
    print_dll(head);
    //to insert 29 after first appearance of 21
    insert_after(head, 21, 29);
    print_dll(head);

    /*Question 6*/
    //create a function to free the whole list

    kill(head);


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `sizeof(Node * )` to `sizeof(Node)` due to malloc reserving you memory for which the pointer points to and it needs the correct amount of needed memory (which is not a pointer but the object itself).
2. `i <= arrSize` might be an overflow, since the size usually is given as amount of memory cells. So you might consider using `i < arrSize`
3. The first while loop in the insert_after might point to invalid memory after the array
4. `Node *new =` is ugly syntax, since new is a keyword in C++. Please never do that, since that will break any code, which is being used in C++.
5. You dont need a temporary element in `kill()`. You can instead going until head points to NULL.
6. delete_element needs the same array checks as `insert_after`

Probably you need to debug the whole thing pasting one function after the other to get it properly working. No guarantee for correctness, since that was abit hard to read without comments and all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do you say "Node *new =..." is obviously wrong? what's wrong with it? This is the syntax my prof has been showing us when using malloc...Anyways, it's the same syntax as `Node *temp = `. The program compiles and runs as it should, it just seems like I misunderstand something about where and when to free up memory.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's a convention not to call things "new" I suppose. I might as well change that as a matter of course, I thought it didn't matter since it's just a name for the pointer.

Comment: `arrSize` is an int which describes the length of the array. Inside the loop, I'm dealing with array elements of the form `array [arrSize-i]`, so letting `i` reach all the way to `arrSize` seems appropriate if I want to access `array[0]`.

Comment: Ah, you want to count backwards. Still thats weird. You start with an offset of 2 to go backwards. I would expect to start at 0 or an explicit comment.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find memory leaks is using valgrind (or a similar tool) in run time.
Valgrind will identify any memory leak or violation you ran through.

to run valgrind in linux environment, all you need to do is:

```
# valgrind --leak-check=full ./my_program
```

In you case it gave mainy theses errors:

```
==28583== Invalid read of size 8
==28583==    at 0x400871: kill (aaa.c:77)
==28583==    by 0x40092D: main (aaa.c:103)
==28583==  Address 0x5204188 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==28583==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28583==    by 0x40073A: create_dll_from_array (aaa.c:29)
==28583==    by 0x4008D9: main (aaa.c:87)
```

this error means the allocation size was too small. as mentioned in another answers it is because you allocate enough memory for a pointer and not for the struct.